# How to store multile images full path into a database so that I can display them in a user home page like Orkut

Tags: php, database-design

I am making an application in which every user has to sign in first and then he can access his home page. Now on the home page, I have given an option of uploading an image. Now if the user is uploading one image I am storing the full path of the uploaded image into a database and from there I can display the image easily by an `img` tag...

But what should I do when the user want to upload many images? Then how should I store their full paths in a database for the same user. Give me an idea just like [Orkut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orkut) or [Facebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook). Should I make a different table with named images and should I store images in different rows with the same username. What should I do?

I don't know the logic. What should I do? How can I upload many images and how can I store their path and what will be the wisest method and how do I display many images on one page (I can display one)?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a folder, named after user name and id and put all their images there.

To display many images on one page, just add more `<img>` tags to the page.

Comment: is it possible that as new user sign up ,at the same time a new folder with his name created so that i can put all images into this..I think i cant manually make folder of user name for each user..

Comment: mkdir() is the function for create folders

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be more of a design question than a PHP question. I would create a separate table to store all paths, this is more normalized.

You still need to handle the UI, but if you are doing a sort of gallery then that is fairly simple with some jQuery sideshows or something like that.

Comment: Ok fine suppose i am creating a table for all images uplaoded by all users but how one will differnciate that this is his/her image showuld i associate users name that is unique for each user with uploaded file so that images can be distinguished

Comment: Add a column for user id, which should be a foreign key to the users table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to use a separate table to store the image paths.  You'll most likely want a record ID, the User ID, and the path to the image.  You could also add a field to contain the sorting order for the images.

Having the sorting order field will allow you to page through the photos if there is more than one page of photos.

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is correct where you suggest creating a separate table with rows containing the image path and the username. The concept that you are dealing with is called [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29). I'd recommend that you take a few minutes to read about this concept, since it is so important to database design.

In this case, you're talking about a one-to-many relationship between the user and the images.